# Click event for dynamically created array of PictureBox's in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, picturebox, eventhandler

I would like some help troubleshooting this segment of code. The method below is supposed to send a string 'selectedFilePath' to a second form 'f2' whenever a PictureBox is clicked. I have an array of Picturebox's and each one needs to send a different string to the second form. The issue I am having is that the same string is sent every single time. vidFilePaths is an array of strings that stores the filepaths. The array of PictureBox's is created dynamically.

```
public void launchMovie(PictureBox[] pics, string[] vidFilePaths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < p-1; i++)
        {
            pics[i].Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
            {
                selectedFilePath = "file:///" + vidFilePaths[i];
                Form2 f2 = new Form2(selectedFilePath);
                this.Hide();
                f2.Show();
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a local variable to store i, else all the events point to the same value (which is `p`) by the end of the method :

```
public void launchMovie(PictureBox[] pics, string[] vidFilePaths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
    {
        int currentIndex = i;
        pics[i].Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
        {
            selectedFilePath = "file:///" + vidFilePaths[currentIndex];
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(selectedFilePath);
            this.Hide();
            f2.Show();
        };
    }
}
```

You need to understand that when an anonymous method captures a local variable (Closure), that variable is stored in a class created by the compiler. This is done in order for that value to be preserved after your method `launchMovie` returns. So all your events actually accesses the same memory address in the managed heap, which is by the time so actually click and the event is raised is `i = p`.

In short words, by the time you click, method `launchMovie` would have ended and `i = p`, this value is stored in a compiler generated class and is used by the event.

Try creating the event in a separate method and see how would you store the value of `i` in order to use it and you would understand more what the compiler is doing.

### Alternative:

As an alternative, you can use `pics[i].Tag` Like this:

```
public void launchMovie(PictureBox[] pics, string[] vidFilePaths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
    {
        pics[i].Tag = vidFilePaths[i];
        pics[i].Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
        {
            int index = 
            selectedFilePath = "file:///" + pics[i].Tag.ToString();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(selectedFilePath);
            this.Hide();
            f2.Show();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with your alternative suggestion. I made a separate method earlier and it made no difference. But the code is working flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
public void launchMovie(PictureBox[] pics, string[] vidFilePaths)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < p-1; i++)
        {
            pics[i].Tag = i;
            pics[i].Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
            {
                int k = Convert.ToInt32((sender as PictureBox).Tag);
                Form2 f2 = new Form2("file:///" + vidFilePaths[k]);
                this.Hide();
                f2.Show();
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are creating PictureBoxes dynamically you have to assign it name and bind the event here like

```
for(int i=0; i<yourCount; i++)
{
  PictureBox pic=new PictureBox();
  pic.Name=i.ToString();
  pics.Click += PickClicked;
}
```

And change the functionality in event handler like this

```
private void PickClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox picBox= sender as PictureBox;
   string selectedFilePath = "file:///" + vidFilePaths[Convert.ToInt(picBox.Name)];
   Form2 f2 = new Form2(selectedFilePath);
   this.Hide();
   f2.Show();
}
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: @David Russo how this answer is not useful?